# How to fix N+1 rule when we have more than one dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a newbie learning ASP.NET MVC from book.I am using NInject to Implement IoC. I have created a data model for Job and Location as below

**Table Name - JobDetails**

```
  JobId<PK>
  LocationId<FK>
  JobName
  CategoryId<FK>
```

**Table Name - Location**

```
 LocationId<PK>
 LocationName
```

**Table Name Category**

```
 CategoryID<PK>
 CategoryName
```

I have created Entities for Location and JobDetails as Below

**JobDetails**

```
public class JobDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int JOBID { get; set; }

    public int LocationID { get; set; }

    public string JOBNAME { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID {get;set;}

    public virtual Location JobLocation{get;set;}

    public virtual Category JobCategory{get;set;}
}
```

Location

```
public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int LocationID{ get; set; }

    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

Category

```
public class Category
{
  public string categoryName {get;set;}
  public int CategoryId {get;set;}
}
```

Also I have my Abstract and Context Class for Job Details and Location as below

```
public interface IJobDetails
{
    IEnumerable<JobDetails> jobDetailsInterface { get; }
}


public interface ILocation
{

    IEnumerable<Location> locationInterface { get; }
} 

public class EFLocationRepository : ILocation
{
    public  EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<Location> locationInterface
    {
        get { return context.Location; }
    }
}

public class EFJobRepository : IJobDetails
{
    public EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<JobDetails> jobDetailsInterface
    {
        get { return context.JobDetails; }
    }
}
```

My Model class for Job and Location are as below

```
public class JobListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<JobDetails> jobDetails { get; set; }
}

public class LocationListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Location> Location { get; set; }
}
```

In my JobDetail Controller I want to display the location name instead of Location Id and Category Name instead of Category ID. My JobDetail controller is as below

```
public class JobController : Controller
{
    public IJobDetails repository;

    public JobController(IJobDetails job)
    {
        repository = job;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.jobDetailsInterface);
    }

}
```

If i use both CategoryName,LocationName in my JobDetails View ,It will lead to N+1 problem.

How can i use Include<> method to have both the model to overcome N+1 problem.

Comment: Strange question. Use the `Include` exactly how it's supposed be used anywhere, e.g. `return context.JobDetails.Include(d => d.Category).Include(d => d.Location);`

Comment: If the `IJobDetails` represents the repository interface, name it `IJobDetailsRepository`. Otherwise it suggests something about the domain model of the entity, maybe an entity itself.

Comment: @IvanStoev..I got your point.I was searching in the function parameter itself!!!

Comment: @WiktorZychla- point noted.Thanks for the suggestion.